# Add space between two tables in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

Just as the title says, I'm using iTextSharp to generate a report. And I want to add a space between two tables, but I don't know how.

this is my code:

```
var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
table1.WidthPercentage = 25;
table1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Factura No: ")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("#1")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Tipo Fact: ")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Contado")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Fecha: ")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("3/17/2017")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cedula: ")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("207080801")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cliente: ")));
table1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Errol")));

//add space here           
PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);
table2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table2.WidthPercentage = 70;
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Producto", boldFont)));
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cantidad", boldFont)));
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Subtotal", boldFont)));
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("PDN130")));
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("2")));
table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("18000")));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`SpacingBefore`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#spacingBefore) or [`SpacingAfter`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#spacingAfter) on the tables. Both take a `float` parameter.

Example :

```
table1.SpacingBefore = 10f;
table1.SpacingAfter = 12.5f;
table2.SpacingBefore = 10f;
table2.SpacingAfter = 12.5f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PdfPTable tblAcNo8 = new PdfPTable(4);
            float[] colWidthsaccing8 = { 150, 250, 30, 500 };
            tblAcNo8.SetWidths(colWidthsaccing8);
            tblAcNo8.SpacingBefore = 10f;
            PdfPCell celladdingo8;

            celladdingo8 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo8.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celladdingo5.BorderWidthRight = 0;
            celladdingo5.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
            celladdingo5.BorderWidthTop = 0;
            celladdingo5.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
            tblAcNo8.AddCell(celladdingo8);
```

Comment: The only apparent detail of your code related to the question is the use of `SpacingBefore`, but that already has been spelled out in accepted answer for three years. So what's your point?